# How to make org understand a custom timestamp format

Tags: org-mode, parse-time

I have the following line below a "TODO":

`SCHEDULED: <Oct 27, 2018 08:30PM>`

Right now, the org-mode throws the following error:

```
Error was: (Not a standard Org time string: Oct 27, 2018 08:30PM); Skipping entry

Bad timestamp ‘Oct 27, 2018 08:30PM’
```

Comment: Why do you want a custom timestamp format? Org already has a lot of tooling to work with its native format. Explaining what you want to get out of a different format would help figure out a solution.

Comment: See the variables `org-display-custom-times` and `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` and `org-time-stamp-formats`.  There use to be a warning on `org-time-stamp-formats`:  "*It is not recommended to change this constant.*"  However, the doc-string for that variable in Emacs 26.1 does not contain the old warning that was present in earlier versions.

Comment: @zck I use an external service that automatically add these tasks to my org file, and that external service has the limitation of writing the timestamp only in the format specified in the description above.

Comment: @lawlist correct me if i'm wrong, but those variables are for displaying the timestamp in a custom format, the underlying timestamp should already be the standard org timestamp format.

Comment: It may behoove you to implement a mechanism to programmatically modify the incorrect / non-standard time-stamps to the standard format as defined by `org-time-stamp-formats`.  The other alternative would be to somehow have the external service add tasks with the proper format.

Comment: May be so, but I like to still figure out a way for org to parse these custom formats.